# Killing bash causes it to respawn itself

Tags: bash, kill

I'm SSHed into my computer at home and I'm trying to format a drive.

`lsof /dev/sdb2` shows:

```
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    1366 mitch  cwd    DIR   8,18    24576    5 /media/mitch/1TBHDD
```

This is causing umount to not unmount that drive. I've tried killing the process with `kill` and `kill -9` but each time, that `/bin/bash` process will come back under a new PID but still using `/dev/sdb2`

How do I kill this bash that just won't seem to die?

Some relevant outputs:

```
mitch@emerald /proc $ ps aux | grep bash
mitch     2339  0.0  0.0  23732  5048 pts/11   Ss   12:10   0:00 -bash
mitch     3711  0.2  0.0  23688  4780 pts/0    Ss+  14:01   0:00 /bin/bash
mitch     3781  0.0  0.0  11748   912 pts/11   S+   14:01   0:00 grep --colour=auto bash
mitch    14159  0.0  0.0  23628  4688 pts/9    Ss+  Jan04   0:00 /bin/bash

mitch@emerald /proc $ lsof /dev/sdb2
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    3711 mitch  cwd    DIR   8,18    24576    5 /media/mitch/1TBHDD
```

Comment: What does `pstree -ps 3711` say? (Replace 3711 with whatever PID of `bash` you get from `lsof`)

Comment: That did it. The output was `init(1)───mdm(1405)───mdm(1431)───cinnamon-sessio(1935)───nemo(2488)───bash(3711)`.. I'll post an answer with the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@muru had me look at the ps tree for that PID

```
pstree -ps 3711
init(1)───mdm(1405)───mdm(1431)───cinnamon-sessio(1935)───nemo(2488)───bash(3711)
```

So you see that nemo (Mint's file manager) is using it. This is because of an addon, [nemo-terminal](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html) installed, which puts a bash shell in nemo. I guess that the behavior of when it dies is to immediately respawn the bash shell.

Killing PID 2488 did the trick.